# How many models of Asynchronous development in .NET?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, model

I am learning asynchronous programming using C# and I usually use `BeginInvoke`, but I am not very sure about the other methods of creating asynchronous application.

I have asked a question about this,see below link for more details:

[How to return T value from BeginInvoke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789544/how-to-return-t-value-from-begininvoke)

In above link, Gravell said that there are four models of asynchronous development

> *There's at least 4, then - a regular callback (non-APM, non-EAP) is also not uncommon*

But Overflow said that there are three:

There are 3 models of asynchronous development in .NET

- **APM** - (`BeginXXX` / `EndXXX`) which you are using here, when the long running task completes, it calls back into your code in the `EndXXX` method
- **EAP** - Event based. In this model, when the long running task completes, an event is raised to inform your code.
- **TPL** - New in .NET 4, this is the Task-based version. It looks most like synchronous programming to client code, using a fluent interface. Its calls back to your code using `ContinueWith`.

Anyone can help me on this?

I have searched google.com a lot, but actually they are using `BeginInvoke` most. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thread.Start` - brutal

`delegate.BeginInvoke/EndInvoke` - 'old' standard

`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` - smart

`TaskFactory.StartNew` - the only way to do it correct (according to `Patterns of parallel programming` book | i recommend you to read it first for disambiguation)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how about the Event based model ?

Comment: @CharlieShi that's just a macro pattern that can be easily done with one of this "methods of creating asyncronous" operations. no matter which one would you choose. BTW in .NET 5 there is going to be a unified method of asynchronous method creation with `async/await` keywords

Comment: then I think in .net 5, it's more easier for us to handle the async function. How about WPF? I am learning it now, I don't know if there is bright future for learning it.

Comment: @CharlieShi, yes in .net 5 all the async stuff is written in regular synchronous mode for the coder. so it's becoming clear and transparent. WPF? why re'u comparing WinForms and WPF? however, the code used to synchronize UI in both the subsystems is almost similar... and simple

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot that can be caught in the term "asynchronous development."

---

For one, you could want to *execute code on a background thread*. I recently updated a [blog post of mine](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html) contrasting several common approaches to executing code in the background. Here's the list, in order from most desirable to least:

1. `Task` (as used by async/await).
2. `Task` (as used by the Task Parallel Library).
3. `BackgroundWorker`.
4. `Delegate.BeginInvoke`.
5. `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.
6. `Thread`

---

On another hand, you could want to *represent an asynchronous operation* (which may or may not be actual code executing on a background thread). In that case, there are several approaches, in order from most desirable to least:

1. `Task` (in the style of the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=204847))
2. `IAsyncResult` with `Begin*`/`End*` methods (which has the unfortunate name [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx)).
3. A component written using the [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkasytyf.aspx).

(As a side note, `BackgroundWorker` is EAP, and `Delegate.BeginInvoke` is APM).

---

On another hand, you could mean *asynchronous programming* in general, which can be interpreted to mean a reactive approach. In this case, there are only two approaches that I know of:

1. [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609).
2. [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkasytyf.aspx).

However, you could make a case that *any* event-driven program is reactive to some extent, so just handling UI events is a (simple) form of "asynchronous programming."

---

Also, these are only the common models. Any platform or library can add more. Here's some off the top of my head:

- The `Socket` class has a special form of APM that can be used to minimize memory allocations. It works very similarly to APM but does not fit the pattern.
- The WinRT runtime (coming in Windows 8) has its own representations of asynchronous operations ([`IAsyncOperation<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206598.aspx) and [`IAsyncInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.iasyncinfo.aspx)).
- Windows Phone has specific support for a [background agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202961%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), which permits you to run code in the background even if your app isn't currently running.

Answer (score 1):

It will most certainly be useful to learn the methods Mikant described for asynchronous development. Just wanted to give you a heads up though that C# 5.0 is completely redesigning how the language deals with async. This will be its main theme along with introducing two new keywords, async and await. You simply call await on a long-running task and it will begin the task and return control to the calling method. Once the task is complete it proceeds with the rest of the code.

Here is an excellent video for the full details of its usage and explanation. It not only describes the old way of performing async operations but a complete review of the new style. It makes writing async applications a ton easier and much more readable with a natural flow.

This is the future of C# async behavior so well worth learning.

http://channel9.msdn.com/events/PDC/PDC10/FT09/

Comment: +1. Jon Skeet also has a wealth of info on the new `async` functionality in his "EduAsync" blog post series: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Eduasync/default.aspx

Comment: @rally25rs Thx for the website you recommand, Appriciate the website very much.